# didDropSampleBuffer is called very often in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, tensorflow

I capture the video and do some analyses on it in `captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer` delegate. but after a short time this method is not called. then `captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didDropSampleBuffer` delegate is called.

When I don't do anything in didOutputSampleBuffer, everything is okay.
I run a tensor flow model in this delegate. And this causes the problem.

***Problem:*** 
**The problem is that when `didDropSampleBuffer` is called, didOutputSampleBuffer will not called again.**

**My solution:** 
 My solution was stoping and starting avCaptureSession. but that caused extra memory usage! Which finally caused my app to crash.

```
 - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
    {
        // ******  do heavy work in this delegate *********
        graph = [TensorflowGraph new];
        predictions = [graph runModelOnPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer orientation: UIDeviceOrientationPortrait CardRect: _vwRect];
    }

    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didDropSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
    {
                CFTypeRef droppedFrameReason = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_DroppedFrameReason, NULL);
                NSLog(@"dropped frame, reason: %@", droppedFrameReason);
    }
```

> ----> dropped frame, reason: OutOfBuffers

According to [https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2445/_index.html]:

> This condition is typically caused by the client holding onto buffers
>   for too long, and can be alleviated by returning buffers to the
>   provider.

**How can I return buffer to the provider?**

**Edited**

After 11 times that `CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:resized fromRect:resized.extent];` line is executed, The `didDropSampleBuffer` is called. commenting `CFRelease(pixelBuffer)` has no difference in result. Does it means that pixelBuffer is not released?

```
CFRetain(pixelBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);

CIImage* ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
ciImage = [ciImage imageByCroppingToRect:cropRect];

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGFloat angle = 0.0;

transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angle);
CIImage* resized = [ciImage imageByApplyingTransform:transform];

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:resized fromRect:resized.extent]; // *********************************

UIImage* _res = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];


CFRelease(pixelBuffer);
```

[1](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2445/_index.html)

Comment: This may sound like a redundant question, but what do you expect to happen? From my point of view, this is what would happen if the didOutputSampleBuffer-method cannot keep up with the camera framerate.

Comment: Something you are doing is likely calling `CFRetain` on `sampleBuffer` but not releasing it. When the capture pipeline runs out of buffers because they're all retained, it stops outputting. This is a memory leak. But you'll probably need to show more code to identify the problem and ensure your existing code snippets are accurate.

Comment: @allenh Thanks. I updated the question.

Comment: You can check the retain count of your pixel buffer using `CFGetRetainCount`. It should be 1 when your delegate returns. `[CIImage initWithCVPixelBuffer:` actually retains the pixel buffer, so if you're keeping the image around anywhere, that can cause problems. Additionally, I have no clue what `[TensorflowGraph runModelOnPixelBuffer:orientation:CardRect:]` does to the pixel buffer. You also need to be calling `CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress` before `CFRelease`.

Comment: @allenh Thanks. It was a really good comment. After [ciimage initWithCvPixelBuffer] how should I release pixel buffer? Should I do something or it will be released automatically?

Comment: The `CIImage` will release the `CVPixelBufferRef` when the `CIImage` is freed (presumably by ARC).